# Inequality on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $$\left|np(z)+(\alpha-1)zp'(z)\right|
\\\geq\left|np(z)+(\alpha-z)p'(z)\right|$$ on $|z|=1,$ and $|\alpha|\geq 1,$
where $p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample: $n=1$, $p(z)=z+1$, $\alpha=1$, $z=-1$.  Then
$$ |np(z)+(\alpha-1)zp'(z)| = 0 < 2 = |np(z)+(\alpha-z)p'(z)| $$